# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.A failure occurs while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable

Tags: react-native, build, expo, build.gradle, build-error

I’m developing an app in React Native and on my device it runs perfectly when I test it but, when I want to build it, the build fails and gives me an error. I’ve been looking for information everywhere but I haven’t found anything and I’m desperate. If someone could help me I would appreciate it.

```
[...]
209 actionable tasks: 209 executed
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
   > Resource compilation failed (Failed to compile values resource file /home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/release/mergeReleaseResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml. Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@57d454a9.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@71679b12.). Check logs for more details.
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 4m 35s
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.
```

One of the things I’ve found is to put wrong colours or dimensions, but it’s Android Studio’s help and in React Native I’d get the error if it was that (and even so I’ve gone over it thousands of times).
Thank you to anyone who takes the trouble to read this message. Best regards!

Looking for information, going through the code, talking to the all mighty ChatGPT, visiting forums and crying a lot.